# Embedded Python occasionally cannot run tkinter until machine restarts

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, tkinter, embed

I have an installation of CPython 3.6 at `%localappdata%\Programs\MyApp\rsc\python` with the following structure:

```
# assume root: %localappdata%\Programs\MyApp\rsc\python

| root
 --- | DLLs
 --- | Lib
 --- | tcl
 --- | tkinter
 # all the contents from the downloaded embedded package
 + python36._pth
 + tcl86t.dll
 + tk86t.dll
```

Directory summaries:

- `DLLs` contains all the MSVCR/P files (including *ucrtbase.dll* and *vcruntime140.dll*)
- `Lib` contains two sub-directories `pip` and `site-packages` as this directory is application maintained (patch system)
- `tcl` direct copy from an installed version of CPython 3.6.0 on the client
- `tkinter` same as the `tcl` directory source

The two DLLs in the `root` directory are also copied from the installed CPython 3.6.0 environment
; the `python36._pth` therefore contains:

```
python36.zip
.
DLLs
Lib
Lib\site-packages
# to an application API included
..\..\..\src
```

After installation, everything works fine and Tkinter is loaded without issue. There are no environment variables set (like `TK_LIBRARY` or `TCL_LIBRARY`) during runtime either. However, on occassion there exists an instance when the program is launched that Python throws a `_tkinter.TclError` when `tk.Tk()` is reached:

```
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
{C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\MyApp\rsc\python\tcl8.6}

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly
```

*Note*: this error occurs on a different system so I had to hand type this, but the upper stacktrace shows that the error is thrown on the call to `root = tk.Tk()`. Prior to this, the only other content related to Tkinter is the import statement.

If I cut the entire application directory and paste it somewhere else, the application runs just fine and Tkinter loads without any errors. If I cut and paste back where it started, the error persists. Leaving alone but restarting the client resolves the issue (temporarily). Of note, altering the program entry to do a `print(sys.path)` shows that the `tcl` directory is found.

Moreover, if the environment is run through the command line, Tkinter is found without a problem:

```
# in cmd.exe
> C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\MyApp\rsc\python\python.exe
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> tk.Tk()
# window appears
```

Thus, for context, the application which is launched via a Windows batch file continues to fail when the environment is launched from it but not directly launched.

Is this a Windows-ism? Is it an embedded Python-ism? What can I do to try and diagnose this?

Comment: When you say _"on occasion"_. Is there a pattern for when it stops working each time?

Comment: @Gerhard Not that I can discern unfortunately. We are on a closed loop network, and so users can only write to a handful of directories, hence the %localappdata% was chosen as it's user specific.